# How to build a modular grid?

Tags: responsive-design, web, grid

A lot of the websites these days is built using grids, pre-made or custom ones. What I noticed is that most of these grids are based on rows, and usually work with the width of the columns, not taking the height of the elements (modules) into account.

I was wondering what the best way (or what the possibilities are) of building a modular grid is? By modular grid I understand such grid where the individual modules could be set in both width and height and be fluid in dependence on the screen. A grid where you'd know you have let's say 12 columns and 9 rows (the width / height of each would be given), and you'd be able to fill it with modules like a mosaic (that makes it sound almost too simple).

Here's an example picture of what I have in mind (picture borrowed from [here](https://www.behance.net/gallery/12322389/Good-Mens-Goods)):

[image]

I came upon a couple of examples, but most of them weren't responsive or were built using Flash. I believe there is a way to do it, just not sure myself how.

I know there might not be ONE correct way, but I'm curious about the possible techniques to go about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This layout technique is commonly known as *masonry*, here are a couple of responsive masonry links to get you started:
http://masonry.desandro.com
http://osvaldas.info/responsive-jquery-masonry-or-pinterest-style-layout

good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know of masonry, but the problem with it (for my purpose) is that 1/ it changes structure, so it doesn't remain a rectangle; 2/ I'd need a clean line at the bottom (like in the design above), while all the masonry layouts seem to have a continuous flow (like e.g. Pinterest)..

Comment: what is the URL of your example @thosetinydreams

Comment: The link to the example is in the question—but it is only a mock-up, doesn't seem the website itself is live. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a live example (none that would be responsive) :(

Comment: Just found two websites with the sort of layout I was looking for: [http://peacheyphotography.co.uk/](http://peacheyphotography.co.uk/) and [http://kae.com/](http://kae.com/), and they both seem to be built on masonry. I will have to have an in-depth look at it then :)

The second website is using classes like grid_box_2x_1y. Any idea if those are also part of masonry or not? It seems like the kind of thing I'm looking for..

Comment: It looks to me as if http://kae.com is using http://packery.metafizzy.co . Not certain, but classes like grid_box_2x_1y may be related to this @thosetinydreams

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say your best option would be to build it using Bootstrap or Foundation, since they are set up to handle this kind of thing.They have classes that, assuming you use a 12 column grid to start, let you pick how many columns they can take up.

links:
http://getbootstrap.com/

http://foundation.zurb.com/

Comment: You are right, however, as I was mentioning in my question, these grids only account with width (how many columns an element can take up) and not height of the elements (apart from distinguishing the content into rows).